# How to enforce line break after method annotation and the rest in one line with checkstyle?

Tags: java, annotations, checkstyle

Which `checkstyle` rule can enforce

```
@Test public void
matchesEmptyElement() {
```

to be invalid and only

```
@Test
public void matchesEmptyElement() {
```

to be valid, i.e., a newline between annotation (if any) access modifier (if any) and not newlines between access modifier and opening bracket?

Comment: I would use a code formatter e.g. in your IDE, to do this as you type, check in code, or on demand. This way you enforce it by ensuring your code is always formatted as desired (without the need to correct it manually)

Comment: @PeterLawrey I'm looking for the specific checkstyle rule and don't want to start a discussion on the advantages of checkstyle in comparison to code formatters.

Comment: I agree it's not an answer to your problem, but a comment on a way to avoid it being a problem in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`AnnotationLocation`](https://checkstyle.org/config_annotation.html#AnnotationLocation) is the check you're looking for:

```
<module name="AnnotationLocation">
  <property name="allowSamelineMultipleAnnotations" value="false"/>
  <property name="allowSamelineSingleParameterlessAnnotation" value="false"/>
  <property name="allowSamelineParameterizedAnnotation" value="false"/>
</module>
```

Or, since `false` is the default value for all these properties, you could reduce some robustness:

```
<module name="AnnotationLocation" />
```